# Could not create a connection with MySQL database cPanel

Tags: php, mysql, cpanel

Someone would think this could be a potentially duplicate question because of the error I'm getting was common which is  **"Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
Exception thrown: 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' in MySql.Data.dll"**

But this issue is specific to this context since as I am getting the error with the server name part of the connection string.

I do have the cPanel and FTP details.

Suppose cPanel address is domainname:2083 and I used that in the connection string as below.

```
string connStr = "server=domainname:2083;user='domain_user';database='domain_database';port=3306;password=123456";
```

because I am repeatedly getting the above error I even tried to give 'localhost' as the server name and it's generating a different error for that which is 
 
 
 
 **"Authentication to host 'localhost' for user 'domain_user' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access denied for user 'domain_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"**

I did add this user(domain_user) manually via cPanel and give all the access privileges.

I tried to give access to the user via phpMyAdmin SQL console but then there was an 'Access denied' error message. That is the reason I add the user via cPanel.

Does anyone have any clue what to use as the server name/ip in this particular scenario? Thank you!

Comment: is this a paid host or local hosting?

Comment: It is a paid server @smith

Comment: then ask the host, they set it up, we didn't

Comment: That's why I've mentioned in the question that I do have cPanel and FTP details with me. I was confusing what to use as the server name in the connection string. @smith

Comment: ftp server != mysql server.